# Terraform plan fails due to content argument missing in local_file resource

Tags: terraform

I have been testing out something using the terraform for_each loop method and ran into this error with the local_file resource.

```
$ cat main.tf 
resource "local_file" "pet" {
  filename = each.value
  for_each = var.filename
}

$ cat variables.tf 
variable "filename" {
    type = set(string)
    default = [
        "/home/user/pets.txt",
        "/home/user/dogs.txt",
        "/home/user/cats.txt"
     ]
}
```

when I run `terraform plan` after init, I see the following errors:

```
$ terraform plan
╷
│ Error: Invalid combination of arguments
│ 
│   with local_file.pet,
│   on main.tf line 1, in resource "local_file" "pet":
│    1: resource "local_file" "pet" {
│
│ "content_base64": one of `content,content_base64,sensitive_content,source` must be specified
╵
╷
│ Error: Invalid combination of arguments
│
│   with local_file.pet,
│   on main.tf line 1, in resource "local_file" "pet":
│    1: resource "local_file" "pet" {
│
│ "source": one of `content,content_base64,sensitive_content,source` must be specified
╵
╷
│ Error: Invalid combination of arguments
│
│   with local_file.pet,
│   on main.tf line 1, in resource "local_file" "pet":
│    1: resource "local_file" "pet" {
│
│ "content": one of `content,content_base64,sensitive_content,source` must be specified
╵
╷
│ Error: Invalid combination of arguments
│
│   with local_file.pet,
│   on main.tf line 1, in resource "local_file" "pet":
│    1: resource "local_file" "pet" {
│
│ "sensitive_content": one of `content,content_base64,sensitive_content,source` must be specified
╵
```

From the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/local/latest/docs/resources/file), I can see argument `content` is optional:

[image]

so I am confused with the above error.

Answer (score 0):

Having encountered the same issue while using the count and for_each meta arguments, I resorted to creating a "content" variable with some dummy text and the errors disappeared afterwards.

But why does hashicorp say they (content, sensitive_content etc) are optional, if without them, the config won't run successfully?

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are using a `Data Source` as a `Resource`. The following change in `main.tf` should solve the problem:

```
data "local_file" "pet" {
   filename = each.value
   for_each = var.filename
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As the error message says:

> one of `content,content_base64,sensitive_content,source` must be specified

The documentation states for each of `content`, `content_base64`, `sensitive_content`, and `source`, that they are *optional* but also that they do conflict with the other three of them, and it also does not specify a default value.
In consequence, you need to specify exactly one of these four arguments.

Also it makes much sense, as you need to define the content of the file you want to be created.

Comment: Thank you, yes, it is common sense that you need to define the content, but the doc says it is optional, so definitely someone will get confused, especially a beginner. The document has to be pretty clear, especially for a popular IAC tool.

Comment: I am sorry to see you disagree. However, I can understand that some people might find this confusing and there are also 2 issues filed on Github regarding this matter. I just submitted a PR to mention it in the docs that one of the arguments has to be specified.